# Django: how to autofill ForeignKey in CreateView

Tags: django

I am trying to autofill a ForeignKey fields in a createview. When I attempt to pass in the site id and save it on submit, I get this error.

```
Cannot assign "u'2'": "FireAlarm.site" must be a "Site" instance.
```

models.py

```
class Site(models.Model):
    ...

class FireAlarm(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    ...
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<site>[0-9]+)/create/$', FireAlarmCreate.as_view(), name='fire-alarm-create'),
```

views.py

```
class FireAlarmCreate(CreateView):
    model = FireAlarm
    form_class = FireAlarmForm
    queryset = FireAlarm.objects.all()
    success_url = '/sites/list'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        fire_alarm = form.save(commit=False)
        fire_alarm.site = self.kwargs['site']

        return super(FireAlarmCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you can't assign the site id `2` to the foreign key.

You can either assign the id to `site_id`:

```
fire_alarm.site_id = self.kwargs['site']
```

Or fetch the site from the database first:

```
site = Site.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['site'])
fire_alarm.site = site
```